# Google drive excel export: Recent change to pivot tables?

Tags: google-drive-api, apache-poi

We currently allow our users to connect to their google drive and download sheets files via the api excel export.

Recently though it seems like something has changed with pivot tables and sheets with those included are no longer compatible with our excel library (we are using apache POI v3.12)

Has anyone else experienced this/is this a known change?

---

Update:

Seems like the issue is actually the excel export functionality in google sheets, it exports pivot tables as blank cells. this seems like a bug?

---

Update2:

[Example file displaying the problem](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EJBqPgPgN0xO1hpz8n_xM1-WZhPCfKU4RffCyeV6N74/edit?usp=sharing)

It looks like when a file is re-uploaded to drive it will display the table correctly again. but when downloaded in excel or open office it is not view able in those applications.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this problem, my pivot table is exporting correctly. Are you still seeing this problem?

Comment: Yes still seeing it, currently using a customers sheet for our testing but I'll  see if we can get a simple example thrown together.

Comment: @EricKoleda I've added another update the question with a simple exmaple of the problem

Comment: It looks like pivot tables aren't exported at all for Open Office documents, but when I export your sheet to Excel it is showing the pivot table data correctly. Either way, this behavior seems to be part of the core product (it happens in the API) and not the API specifically. You're best bet is to post in the Google Sheets Help Forum.

Comment: @EricKoleda What Version of excel were you using?

Comment: I was exporting to Excel format but opening in Open Office.

Comment: This question isn't about programming related to Google Apps, so it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It belongs on [WebApps](//webapps.stackexchange.com/), or the Google Apps support forum.